# Flutter grant permission

Tags: android, permissions, flutter, xiaomi

I struggle to ask ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION on a XIAOMI REDMI NOTE 4 which is running Android 6.0.

I tried to use geocoder and location. It works on iphone and a samsung on Android 8 (don't know the name).

TL;DR : the permission is never ask and not visible in app settings and Xiaomi.

Here is my code:

Android

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

private static final String CHANNEL_GPS = "runtimepermission/access_fine_location";
private PermissionCallback getAccessFineLocationPermissionCallback;
private boolean rationaleJustShown = false;
private static final int GET_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID = 1234;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL_GPS).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, final MethodChannel.Result result) {
                    getAccessFineLocationPermissionCallback = new PermissionCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void granted() {
                            rationaleJustShown = false;
                            result.success(0);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void denied() {
                            rationaleJustShown = false;
                            result.success(1);
                        }
                    };
                    if (call.method.equals("hasPermission")) {
                        askPermission();
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void askPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            GET_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID);
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    System.out.println("requestCode:" + requestCode);
    for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
        System.out.println("grandResult[i]:" + grantResult);
    }

    switch (requestCode) {
        case GET_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getAccessFineLocationPermissionCallback.granted();
            } else {
                getAccessFineLocationPermissionCallback.denied();
            }
            return;
    }
}

public interface PermissionCallback {
    void granted();

    void denied();
}
```

Flutter:

```
static const _methodChannel = const MethodChannel('runtimepermission/access_fine_location');
  Future<PermissionState> canGetLocation() async {
    try {
      final int result = await _methodChannel.invokeMethod('hasPermission');
      return new Future.value(PermissionState.values.elementAt(result));
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Exception ' + e.toString());
    }
    return new Future.value(PermissionState.DENIED);
  }
```

It throws a PlatformException with an error message: The user explicitly denied the use of location services for this app or location services are currently disabled in Settings.

On the phone, the popup never shows up, and the permission is not displayed in settings > installed app > my app > permissions

Can you help me ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache problem.
If you're experiencing odd problems like I had, clean the cache :)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. I was able to solve mine by enabling the app to auto init and dont optimize battery. It seems to be a xiaomi only problem with no plugins or flutter dev solution so far. My recommendation is to make a screen teaching the user what to do and redirect them

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to close my issue.
It was a cache problem, Flutter was not able to clean its own cache, I had to do it manually.